# C++ variadic templates with non-types, recursion with two parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, syntax-error, variadic-templates

As part of learning to use templates I tried to do the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template< size_t ...A >
struct Test;

//base
template< size_t a >
struct Test< a >{
    template< size_t b >
    constexpr static void compare(){
        //Do something with a, b
        //static_assert( a==b, "" )
        std::cout << a << "==" << b << "? " << ((a==b) ? "yes":"no") << "\n";
    }
};

//recursion
template< size_t a, size_t ...A >
struct Test<a , A...> {
    template< size_t b, size_t ...B >
    constexpr static void compare(){
        //Do something with a, b
        //static_assert( a==b, "" )
        std::cout << a << "==" << b << "? " << ((a==b) ? "yes":"no") << "\n";

        //Compile error
        Test<A...>::compare<B...>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test< 2 >::compare< 2 >();

    Test< 2, 3 >::compare< 2, 1 >();   
}
```

In the hope of comparing two parameter packs.
But I get the following compile error:

```
In static member function ‘static constexpr void Test<a, A ...>::compare()’:
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘...’ token
      |         Test<A...>::compare<B...>();
      |                              ^~~
      |                              ;
error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
      |         Test<A...>::compare<B...>();
      |                     ~~~~~~~^~
```

Most sources online seem to deal with type parameters or with just one parameter pack.
Simply googling the errors didn't yield much either.

Comment: TL;DR; `Test<A...>::compare<B...>();` -> `Test<A...>::template compare<B...>();`

Comment: @super, this does fix it. Do you know where it is explained why this is needed?

Comment: Yes. Your question was closed as a duplicate. Check the duplicate question maybe... ?